# Changing two labels simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/6yjRL/

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <label id="num1label"/>
        +
        <label id="num2label" />
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var num1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

$(function () {
    $("#num1label").text(num1);            
    $("#num2label").text(num2);
});
```

My desired result is a text showing "5 + 2" for example. But only one label changes value and the "+" gets removed for some reason.

Comment: Remember that the [`<label>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) element is intended to be associated to an input or form element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong element, bad markup. Use:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span id="num1label"></span>
        +
        <span id="num2label"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your code failed because the `<label>` tag isn't self-closing; the forgiving browser thinks they should be nested and that you forgot the closing tags, so it renders them that way.

However, the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label) tag is used for providing an annotation for an input element. Correctly used, it must be associated with a `<form>` element, either as a descendant or through the `form` attribute (HTML5). For in-line text you can (*and should*) use the `<span>` element.

Comment: Indeed, this was correct. I'll accept your answer when I can (in 10min)

Answer (score 1):

You can't omit the end-tag for `label` elements. The resulting markup is not what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to this

```
<body>
        <label id="num1label"></label>
        +
        <label id="num2label"></label>
    </body>
```

Comment: I know this works, but why does this work? Why won't <label /> work?

Comment: @Tjirp Because `<label>` isn't self-closing, so the browser sees that and thinks the element isn't closed and adds its own `</label>`. The problem is, when the browser sees two successive 'unclosed' elements, it nests the second inside the first as `<label><label></label></label>`...hence the problem here.